# Saving weights of PyTorch VGG model after every iteration

Tags: model, pytorch

The same weights of VGG classifier get saved after every iteration. But the dictionary `classifier_weights` contains same weights at every iteration.

Below is the code snippet:

```
classifier_weights = {}
task_model.train()

for iter_count in range(self.args.train_iterations):
    if iter_count != 0 and iter_count % lr_change == 0:
        for param in optim_task_model.param_groups:
            param['lr'] = param['lr'] / 10

     # task_model step
        preds = task_model(labeled_imgs)
        task_loss = self.ce_loss(preds, labels)
        optim_task_model.zero_grad()
        task_loss.backward()
        optim_task_model.step()

        if iter_count > self.args.weight_save_iter:
            classifier_weights[iter_count - self.args.weight_save_iter - 1] = {}
            classifier_weights[iter_count - self.args.weight_save_iter - 1][0] = task_model.classifier[0].weight.data
            classifier_weights[iter_count - self.args.weight_save_iter - 1][1] = task_model.classifier[3].weight.data
            classifier_weights[iter_count - self.args.weight_save_iter - 1][2] = task_model.classifier[6].weight.data
```

Comment: To save the weights properly in pytorch you should use the following function: ```torch.save(model.state_dict(), "weights.pt")```

Comment: Yes, that's one way. But I need to save them in a dictionary for further use. 
I apologize for not mentioning that earlier.

Comment: Maybe you can find a way to to get them in a directory directly from the .pt file, good luck!